# Flask - send_from_directory returns old file

Tags: pdf, flask, pdftk

When I fill and submit pdf form, send_from_directory returns the old file. I use pdftk to push fdf to pdf and flatten, but if I give the same filename as output with the old one, Flask shows the old file. Why isn't it overwritten by the new one? Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Flask issue. Show code that we can run and that reproduces your described behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def show_pdf_form(filename):
return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)

@app.route('/get_data_as_fdf', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def get_pdf_data_as_fdf():

# create fdf file
fdf_string = request.data
fdf_file = open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], "data.fdf"), "w")
fdf_file.write(fdf_string)
fdf_file.close()

# merge fdf to pdf and flatten pdf
call(["pdftk", "./uploads/send_data_as_fdf.pdf", "fill_form",
      "./uploads/data.fdf", "output", "output.pdf", "flatten"])

return redirect(url_for('show_pdf_form', filename = filename))
```

These are related code snippets. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Flask `send_from_directory` uses `send_file` internally. `send_file` has cache timeout which you can set to 0.

Try clearing the cache and hitting the URL in incognito mode. if it works, you can do:

```
 send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename, cache_timeout=0)
```

Or you can try any of the options mentioned in:
[Disabling caching in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34066804/disabling-caching-in-flask)