# Disabling caching in Flask

Tags: python, caching, flask

I have some caching issues. I'm running very small web-application which reads one frame, saves it to the disk and then shows it in browsers window.

I know, it is probably not the best solution, but every time I save this read frame with the same name and therefor any browser will cache it.

I tried to use html meta-tags - no success:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Also, I have tried this one (flask-specific):

```
resp.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
resp.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
resp.headers["Expires"] = "0"
```

This is how I tried to modify `resp` headers:

```
r = make_response(render_template('video.html', video_info=video_info))

r.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
r.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
r.headers["Expires"] = "0"
```

Still both Google Chrome and Safari do caching.

What might be the problem here?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

OK,

finally it worked with this:

```
@app.after_request
def add_header(r):
    """
    Add headers to both force latest IE rendering engine or Chrome Frame,
    and also to cache the rendered page for 10 minutes.
    """
    r.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    r.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    r.headers["Expires"] = "0"
    r.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=0'
    return r
```

If you add this, this function will called after each request done. Please,see [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.after_request)

I would be happy, if anyone could explain me why this headers overwriting did not work from the page handler?

Thank you.

Comment: You told the browser not to cache the response containing the contents of video.html. You need to tell it not to cache the response containing the frame itself.

Comment: Note that you are overwriting the `r.headers["Cache-Control"]` from the first line in the second last line. So effectively your response will only have `'public, max-age=0'` set for `Cache-Control`

Comment: Related: Instead of manually specifying the headers, it is now possible with Flask 1.0.2 to access the underlying `cache_control` object of the `Response` instance, then set the [`no_cache`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.ResponseCacheControl.no_cache) field to `True` (and other related fields). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23115561/2745495.

Comment: from MDN docs it looks like `no-store` is the only thing required, and is better practice to put only that when settings `Cache-Control`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control. I.e. `Cache-Control: no-store` in the server response to prevent caching.

Answer (score 44):

If you have always the same problem, that Flask didn't see the updates in JS and CSS files, that because by default, Flask has as max-age value 12 hours. You can set it to 0 to resolve the problem like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0
```

Refer to [its documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT) for details.

Comment: This was a much simpler solution, and all I needed to do

Answer (score 4):

A combination of
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0 in the python file

and
hard reload (command + shift + R) of the chrome browser worked for me as it seems Chrome caches the static files