# Python flask client side cached files stuck in pending on regular load

Tags: python, flask

The issue I am running into is that whenever I do a normal refresh or load a page from my flask server a random set of static files will get stuck in a pending state. There are no errors in the local client side console or in the flask logs.

What I see on load is:

[image: Example Stuck State]

Notice that there are a couple files stuck in pending. This tends to be different every time but always a static file.

When I hit stop and then force refresh (ctrl + F5) everything loads fine:

[image: After Force Refresh]

Flask is in dev mode but I'm not getting an errors server side or client side popping up to help me figure out what is going on. I have tried adding the option to use --with-threads. That made no difference for me. I am using Flask `session` if that makes any difference.

**Update**
This isn't the solution but is a work around for the moment. By using the logic to disable cache from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34066804/disabling-caching-in-flask). I can get everything to load normally by forcing the local client side cache to be disabled. Obviously this isn't optimal as it impacts load times.

```
@app.after_request
def add_header(r):
    """
    Add headers to both force latest IE rendering engine or Chrome Frame,
    and also to cache the rendered page for 10 minutes.
    """
    r.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    r.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    r.headers["Expires"] = "0"
    return r
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I had a similar issue recently due to some conflict in versions of packages installed. I resolved it by installing the latest of each package.

Comment: I think that might have been my issue. The problem has gone away at some point and I never did pinpoint the exact cause.